# Creating an array based on the percentage difference of each values of a previous element

Tags: arrays, swift, flatmap

I have an array that is the following:

```
var array: [Double] = [4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 6]
```

What I would like to do is create a new array from this array that contains the percentage difference of each value compared to its previous one. So my above array would look like:

```
var newArray = [0, 25, -60, 100, -25, 100]
```

If that makes sense? Any help is greatly appreciated, many thanks!!

Comment: Shouldn't the `newArray` in fact be `[0, 25, -60, 100, -25, 100]`?

Comment: Of course, sorry for the mistake!! (thanks for spotting it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be conveniently done with `zip()` to enumerate over pairs
of adjacent array elements:

```
let array: [Double] = [4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 6]

let percentages = [0] + zip(array, array.dropFirst()).map {
    (old, new) in
    return 100.0 * (new - old) / old
}

print(percentages) // [0.0, 25.0, -60.0, 100.0, -25.0, 100.0]
```

(It is assumed that none of the array elements is zero.)

Or with shorthand syntax:

```
let percentages = [0] + zip(array, array.dropFirst()).map {
    100.0 * ($1 - $0) / $0
}
```

Comment: Very nice and Swifty solution.

Comment: Great answer, although one of the items in the OPs example **is** zero, so perhaps assuming that zero isn't a valid value is risky. I'd suggest returning an array of Optionals where the result is mapped to nil if the item is zero, to avoid a divide-by-zero crash.

Comment: @DuncanC: There is no zero in OP's example `[4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 6]` – `[0, 25, -60, 100, -25, 100]` is the desired *result array,* and the leading zero corresponds to the initial array element which has no predecessor to compare with.

Comment: @DuncanC: (cont.) But you are right, that would be a possible way to handle zeros. Or return zero if the predecessor is zero. Without additional information from OP I don't want to guess what the intended result is in those case. The above code hopefully suffices for a start.

Comment: My mistake. The zero was in the output, not the input.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
func percentageDifference(num1: Double, num2: Double) -> Double {
    return (num2 - num1) / num1 * 100
}

var array: [Double] = [4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 6]
var resultArray: [Double] = [0]

for i in (1..<array.count) {
    resultArray.append(percentageDifference(num1: array[i-1], num2: array[i]))
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly 

Answer (score 2):

You can use a var to keep a reference of the last element and use defer to update it inside map:

```
extension Collection where Element: FloatingPoint {
    var percentageDifference: [Element] {
        guard var last = first else { return [] }
        return map { element in
            defer { last = element }
            return (element - last) / last * 100
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
let numbers: [Double] = [4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 6]
let percentageDifference = numbers.percentageDifference
print(percentageDifference)   // "[0.0, 25.0, -60.0, 100.0, -25.0, 100.0]\n"
```

Comment: Thanks very much, nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

One-liner: you could iterate over the indices and compute the result:

```
let array: [Double] = [4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 6]
let newArray = array.indices.map { i in (array[i] - array[max(0,i-1)]) / array[max(0, i-1)] * 100.0 }
print(newArray) // [0.0, 25.0, -60.0, 100.0, -25.0, 100.0]
```

Has a minor code duplication, however it does it job in a performant manner, I'd say :)